# How can apps make requests in the background without permission?

Tags: iphone, ios, privacy

When I turn on [Charles Proxy](https://apps.apple.com/app/charles-proxy/id1134218562) on iOS the result is shocking.

There are several apps (which I haven't used recently) making requests in the background even though I've turned off permissions for Background App Refresh or Notifications for those apps.

I thought that with Background App Refresh turned off an app is dormant except when I open it?

These apps are useful once in a while but with that behavior I'll have to delete them if Apple's settings don't do what they suggest they do.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you provide an example of such an app? According to https://support.apple.com/HT202070, "After you switch to a different app, some apps run for a short period of time before they're set to a suspended state." Do you think requests exceed the "short period of time" documented by Apple?